# How to deploy GCP functions with Golang 1.15 (Serverless framework)

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

Is there a way to deploy GCP function with **Go 1.15** using Serverless framework ?

Looks like **1.15** is available (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime) but I can't find a way to do it with Serverless.

serverless.yml

```
...
provider:
  name: google
  runtime: go115
...
```

I have this `Invalid runtime` error :

```
{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"The request has errors","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"field":"runtime","description":"Invalid runtime."}]}],"statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**************/locations/us-central1/functions/*****","httpMethod":"PATCH"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GO1.15 runtime is not supported by the [regular](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--runtime) and [beta version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy#--runtime) of Cloud Functions.

Use Go1.13 instead, or use Cloud Run.